# Problem with transition in Bootstrap 5.5.2 on bundle.js

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-5

I tried to implement [zoom.js](https://github.com/fat/zoom.js) used to zoom images like in medium site.

I linked both the css and js file, it works. But whenever I zoom out the transition doesn't work. I suspected the bootstrap's bundlejs file. I downgraded from 5.2.2 to 3.0.0 and it worked fine. I exactly don't know what's happening, please help me with that.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't knew what you have written in your code as you haven't attached it but I think what you have done is that you used code from the old bootstrap (3.0.0) and that code is changed for bootstrap 5.2.2. Bootstrap changes it's code a little bit in some versions and make documentation of it very clearly. You should go to it's documentation page for more assistance and you can also post your code here if you are unsure what is changed in bootstrap 5.